# Vertically and horizontally always align image in center of space in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I have a Bootstrap Fixed responsive Navigation Bar with an image on the left of the buttons. I used media queries to make the spacing responsive and now I have this code:

My CSS:

```
.nav > li > a:hover
{
    background-color: #FCC;
}
.navbar-header
{
    float: right;
}
.navbar-default
{
    background-color: #00b5fe;
    border-color: #0089ff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand
{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus
{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text
{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a
{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus
{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu
{
    background-color: #00b5fe;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a
{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus
{
    background-color: #0089ff;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > .divider
{
    background-color: #00b5fe;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus
{
    background-color: #0089ff;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus
{
    background-color: #0089ff;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle
{
    border-color: #0089ff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus
{
    background-color: #0089ff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form
{
    border-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link
{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover
{
    color: #ffffff;
}
@media (max-width: 767px)
{
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a
    {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus
    {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus
    {
        background-color: #0089ff;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 767px)
{
    body
    {
        padding-top: 230px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px)
{
    body
    {
        padding-top: 130px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
{
    #resize
    {
        width: 30%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
{
    #alignp
    {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

And My HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar-blue">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                </button>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <p id="centerp">
                <img align="left" id="resize" width="60%" src="../logo.png" alt="Coding Kids" style="display:block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: 20px;">
            </p>
            <br />
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a></a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/">Products<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Silver</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Silver+</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gold</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Gold+</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUp"><img src="images/register.png" width="20"> Sign Up</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logIn"><img src="images/login.png" width="20"> Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="signUp" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Sign Up</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Sign Up Box Goes Here</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="logIn" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Login Box Goes Here</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="well">
        {tag_pagecontent}
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color: black; clear: both;">
        <div class="panel-body" style="background-color: black; color: white;">&copy; Coding Kids</div>
    </div>
```

A working version of this page is [here](http://codingkids.businesscatalyst.com).

As you can see in my working version, as you resize the window, the logo changes position. At the moment, it doesn't look very neat as it keeps changing position. All I want is for the logo to always be centred horizontally and vertically in the space it has. How would I go about editing my CSS and media queries to suit this?

Comment: This doesn't work: "A working version of this page is here."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changing the alignment should do the trick.

```
            <img align="centre" id="resize" width="60%" src="../logo.png" alt="Coding Kids" style="display:block; margin-bottom:20px;>
```

If it doesn't try adding a div and settling the image in it:

```
            <div align="centre"><img align="left" id="resize" width="60%" src="../logo.png" alt="Coding Kids" style="display:block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>
```

You can also use the

```
<div style="text-align:centre;">
```

CSS rule instead.

Comment: Isn't the `align` attribute depreciated in HTML5

Comment: Oh. I didn't notice that. I will change that. The second example you gave kinda works (I have updated the example page), but the images vertical and horizontal alignment still doesn't adjust with the navigation bar.

Comment: The text-align property of the div.

Comment: Both the vertical and the horizontal alignments are still not working :-(

Comment: Did you remove the    <img align> ?

Comment: Yes but now my image is not inline with the navigation bar, and the vertical align still doesn't work